# How do I fit an image in a bootstrap jumbotron?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can I fit an image inside a bootstrap jumbotron? I have tried applying `background-size : cover;`  to the .jumbotron class in css but it never worked for me. I have also tried resizing the image but that would render it non-responsive. I am quite new to bootstrap so any help would be appreciated!

I also need the image to be as a background in the jumbotron so that any text, button or image would appear over it.

Please check this : http://www.bootply.com/xy1ypW7UpK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the image to be a backgroud change class to:

```
.jumbotron1 {
  padding: 30px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  text-align: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png")
}
```